# jquery progress bas is not function

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

when i call 
               " $("#progressbar").progressbar({"    the computer tell me "progress bar is not function"
also the progress barr is not even displayed on the screen
use visual studio 2015 prograo in asp . net framework 4.5

```
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
 <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function (evt) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var data = new FormData();
            var files = $("#FileUpload1").get(0).files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
            }
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var progress = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
                    $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", progress);
                }
            }, false);
            xhr.open("POST", "UploadHandler.ashx");
            xhr.send(data);

            $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                max: 100,
                change: function (evt, ui) {
                    $("#progresslabel").text($("#progressbar").progressbar("value") + "%");
                },
                complete: function (evt, ui) {
                    $("#progresslabel").text("File upload successful!");
                }
            });
            evt.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

body

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select File(s) to Upload :"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="progressbar" class="progressbar">
        <div id="progresslabel" class="progressbarlabel">zzz</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: jquery-ui might need to be loaded after jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
```